# Generate specific reduced words that "violate freeness"

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ be a group, and let $g_1,g_2\in G$ be nontrivial elements that do not commute.

If $g$ and $h$ are not free as group elements,
then the only *a priori* information this provides us is that there exists a sequence of alternating indices $i(1)\neq i(2)\neq\cdots\neq i(s)$ (with $i(1),\ldots,i(s)\in\{1,2\}$) and exponents $m(1),\ldots,m(s)\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ such that

- $g_{i(l)}^{m(l)}\neq e$ for all $l\leq s$; and
- $g_{i(1)}^{m(1)}\cdots g_{i(s)}^{m(s)}=e,$

that is, a reduced word in $g_1$ and $g_2$ that is equal to the neutral element $e$.

My questions are the following:

> 1. Assuming that $i(1)=i(s)$, is it possible to generate another reduced word $g_{j(1)}^{n(1)}\cdots g_{j(t)}^{n(t)}$ such that $g_{j(1)}^{n(1)}\cdots g_{j(t)}^{n(t)}=e$ and $j(1)\neq j(t)$?
> 2. Assuming that $i(1)\neq i(s)$, is it possible to generate another reduced word $g_{j(1)}^{n(1)}\cdots g_{j(t)}^{n(t)}$ such that $g_{j(1)}^{n(1)}\cdots g_{j(t)}^{n(t)}=e$ and $j(1)=j(t)$ for both $j(1)=1$ and $j(t)=2$?

---

So far, I have been completely unable to answer the first question, and I can only partially answer the second question as follows:

1. If the orders of both $g_{i(1)}$ and $g_{i(s)}$ are strictly greater than two (or infinite),
   then it is possible to find $p,q\in\mathbb Z$ such that $g_{i(1)}^p,g_{i(1)}^{m(1)+p},g_{i(s)}^q,g_{i(s)}^{m(s)+q}\neq e$,
   yet
   $$g_{i(1)}^{m(1)+p}\cdots g_{i(s)}^{m(s)}g_{i(1)}^{-p}=e$$
   and
   $$g_{i(s)}^{-q}g_{i(1)}^{m(1)}\cdots g_{i(s)}^{m(s)+q}=e$$
2. If at least one of the orders of $g_{i(1)}$ and $g_{i(s)}$ is equal to $2$,
   I don't know.

Comment: Yes, for (1), you can conjugate the word by $g_{i(1)}^{m(1)}$ to get the first and last syllables to be distinct. I don't yet understand the second question, though.

Comment: @James If the reduced word I start with is something like $g_1^{m(1)}g_2^{m(2)}\cdots g_2^{m(2)}=e$, I'd like to be able to generate reduced words like $g_1^{n(1)}g_2^{n(2)}\cdots g_1^{n(t)}=e$ and $g_2^{n(1)}g_1^{n(2)}\cdots g_2^{n(t)}=e$. As for conjugating by $g_{i(1)}^{m(1)}$ for question 1, this could work for a word like $g_1g_2g_1^2=e$, which turns into $g_1^{-1}g_1g_2g_1^2g_1=g_2g_1^3$, but then wouldn't you have to make hypotheses about the order of $g_1$? And then what about words like $g_1g_2g_1$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  What hypothesis do you think you need about the order of $g_1$? If everything collapses, I think you're going to contradict your assumption that $g_1$ and $g_2$ do not commute.

Comment: Regarding your question in comments about words like $g_2 g_1^3$ and words like $g_1 g_2 g_1$, you have to tell us whether your question is about words whose letters are symbols of the form $g_1^i, g_2^j$, or whether instead your question is about words whose letters are the *group elements* of the form $g_1^i, g_2^j$.

Comment: My comment is about group elements. When I mention *reduced word*, I mean in the sense that one would write $g_2g_1g_1g_1=g_2g_1^3$ if the order of $g_1$ is not three. However, as James mentioned, I think that if the element collapses, I would run into contradictions (i.e., one of $g_1$ or $g_2$ would have to be trivial).